# SSRS Report Builder Sub-Report Sorting

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that contains 20 sub reports in it. Each sub-report represents a phase in a specific cycle. All sub-reports are identical in formatting and such, containing specific data to that phase and displaying a start and end date. I was wondering if there is a way in Report Builder to essentially have those sub-reports be dynamic and sort themselves based on their specific start dates instead of just displaying them the one I have them listed in my report?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple.

You already have you main report and sub reports so that's good. I assume your subreport takes a parameter which indicates the phase.

Assuming this, let's say the parameter your sub-report accepts is called `pPhase`

1. In your main report, remove all the existing sub reports
2. Next, create a dataset, lets call it `dsLoop`
3. Set `dsLoop`s dataset query to return the phases in order for example `SELECT DISTINCT PhaseNumber from myTable ORDER BY PhaseNumber`
4. Now add a table control, remove the header row and two of the columns leaving just a single cell.
5. Make this cell as wide as you need, wide enough for your subreport, height does not matter.
6. Set the `DataSetName` property of the table to `dsLoop`
7. In the remaining cell, right-click and choose `Insert --> Subreport`. A subreport control will fill the cell.
8. Right-Click the subreport control and choose `Subreport Properties`, choose your subreport from the list
9. Still in the subreport properties, click the parameters tab, add a new parameter.
10. Set the Name to the parameter name that your subreport accepts (`pPhase` in our
     example) . Finally, set the Value to the name of the field that contains
     your parameter data (`PhaseNumber` in our example)

That's it...

Now when you main report runs, a row will be created in your table for each entry in `dsLoop`, each row will contain your subreport and each will have the parameter passed to it that is specific to each row.

If you have any issues, let me know and I'll post a full example.

Comment: Alan, thanks so much for the feedback. I do have another comment though. So I'll essentially have 20 subreports though if that makes sense... Will I need to create a row in my table for each subreport? Thanks!

Comment: Also, another thing I just came across was an error when I run the report that says "Error: Subreport could not be shown.".  I was also wondering if I select the entire table and go to the "Sorting" tab, will that help accomplish my goal and make the sub-reports order themselves accordingly? Thanks.

Comment: And also to clarify. Each phase as its own report that represents all of its data. So when I add a subreport into my main report, it essentially is just pulling one of the 20 other reports as it's subreport to display the phase if that makes sense... So what I had was all 20 reports in a main report as subreports and I just want them to order themselves based on their start dates. Sorry if I am confusing! Thank you.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you only need one main report and one subreport. The subreport will get called 20 times, once for each phase. What parameter(s) does your subreport currently take?

Comment: Actually I just read it again. I see you have 21 reports in total. Id the 20 sub reports are identical in structure but each just filters data for each phase then you need to create a single subreport and pass parameters to it. You need to let me know how you currently filter the data. Show me the basics of the dataset query in the subreports.

Comment: I must've misspoke before, so the subreports which are the 20 phases aren't 100% identical... They have a lot of static text that is the same but it's mostly their formatting is very close together if that makes sense...

Comment: are the datasets in each subreport the same structure (i.e. do the datasets return the same field names and types)

Comment: Yeah so they all use the same datasets... But for example, this one phase displays HWFI Flush Time data.... And this other phase will display Sure Vessel statistics... They all have a Phase Start and Phase End time at the top of the report - All those times are in the same exact table in SQL as well. So it is more so they share formatting and style of report more so than identical statistics... SO I thought there could be a way report builder would display these 20 sub-reports in order based off of the times in the report if that makes sense...

Comment: I think you'll have to post some sample data and your dataset query(s) so I can get an idea of exactly what makes each sub report different. It might still be possible to use a single subreport which will make life easier.

Comment: How would you like to go about this? Email? Chat?

Comment: I'm in the UK so at some point tomorrow, start a private chat and we can take it from there. In the meantime, prep some dummy data and get the dataset queries ready so you can send them to me.

Comment: Hey Alan, I am ready to provide you with some dummy data at this point if that is alright. Please let me know how to private chat you so I can provide screen shots and other items. Thank you.

Comment: I'm away for a few days so I'll try to get back to you on Thursday.